# How can I pass two different questions randomly on the same input dialog box?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am creating a quiz with 15 questions that asks students what the area and perimeter are of a rectangle. I have to keep track of the answers from each question. I am having trouble figuring out how to ask two different questions randomly using `JOptionPane`.

Do I need two separate input dialog boxes for each question?

```
package proj3;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Project4App {
    public static void main( String args[ ] ) {

        Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle();

        String perimeterQuestion = new String("What is the perimeter of this rectangle?");
        String areaQuestion = new String("What is the area of this rectangle?");

        int rightAnswers = 0;
        int wrongAnswers = 0;
        String perimeterAnswer;
        int a = 0;


        int questionNumber[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};



        for (int i = 0; i < questionNumber.length; i++ ) {
            newRectangle.dimensions();
            perimeterAnswer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Question #" + questionNumber[0] + "\n" + perimeterQuestion + "\n" 
        + newRectangle.toString());
            a = Integer.parseInt(perimeterAnswer);
            if (a == newRectangle.findPerimeter()) {
                rightAnswers += 1;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations! You got it correct!");
            }
            else {
                wrongAnswers +=1;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The correct answer was " + newRectangle.findPerimeter());
            }

            questionNumber[0] += 1; 
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: *"I am having trouble figuring out how to ask two different questions randomly using JOptionPane."* What part are you stuck with? Making the questions random? Or placing both area and perimeter questions in the same dialog?

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an Object that has two properties: question and answer
2. Add all the Objects to an `ArrayList`
3. Use `Collections.sort(...)` to sort the questions in random order
4. Remove the question from index 0 and display the question in a new  JOptionPane
5. Validate the answer

Repeat steps 4-5 until finished.

Comment: So I should but both the questions and answers in the same ArrayList?

Comment: @ScottZachary, that is NOT was I suggested. I suggested you create a custom Object with two properties. You know something like a Point object. When you create the Point object you pass in the x/y values as parameters. Then you have getX() and gety() method to access the data. Well you have the same situation except your two properties are question/answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to put all of your answers into an array. Then get a random number in the range of the size of the array ([How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)) and then proceed to pick that index out of the array of all your questions. Then set the value of the dialogue box to that value. This will create a randomization of your questions.